# Undo a Git commit after push using reverse patch?

Tags: git

I've pushed a commit and I want to revert changes introduced by this commit by applying and committing a reversed patch. How do I do it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use git-revert.

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html

Comment: This is not a good option if you use a PR flow; in those cases you will want to make a new commit that put the changes from one commit back to what they were.

Answer (score 146):

Use

```
git revert HEAD
```

This will create a patch that reverts the last commit and commit that patch as a new commit.

If you want to revert a specific earlier version, use

```
git revert <revision>
```

see also: http://schacon.github.com/git/git-revert.html

Answer (score 4):

simply use

for committed file:

```
git revert <SHA1 ID>
```

for non-committed file:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```