# Edit an incorrect commit message in Git that has already been pushed

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit

I did a Git commit and push, but wrote the totally wrong thing in the comment.

How do I change the comment? I have already pushed the commit to the remote.

Comment: you mean you _haven't_ pushed the commit to anyone?

Comment: there's no such thing as a push message.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/git-undo-last-commit

Comment: Just in case: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6441902/777186) what you are looking for?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457379/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git-ive-pushed

Comment: @vertti it's commit message, sorry for ommision

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`git commit --amend` will allow you to edit the commit message.

If you already pushed that commit, you need to run `git push --force`. **Only do that if you are sure nobody pulled it yet!**

If people pulled the commit from your repo, simply leave the message as it is.

Comment: I did git commit --amend and modified the message, but after that i don't know what to do. Here is all available commands
^G Get Help            ^O WriteOut            ^R Read File           ^Y Prev Page           ^K Cut Text            ^C Cur Pos
^X Exit                ^J Justify             ^W Where Is            ^V Next Page           ^U UnCut Text          ^T To Spell

Comment: So you don't know how to use your default editor?! It looks like `nano`, so simply press `CTRL+X`, followed by `Y`, followed by `RETURN`

Comment: sorry it doesn't help me, because I want to change commit message after pushing. git commit --amend  doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: @emilan If you want to change it, after you pushed, you will need to do as ThiefMaster says and push again with the --force option.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not suggested to use `--force` during `git push` as it has potential to reset the remote branch to your local branch changes, so the people presently working on the remote branch or sub-branch from the remote branch will be working on out of sync files, as the parent branch is hard reset.

So there is a cleaner way to handle this.

*For the latest commit: In your current branch:*

1. `git commit --amend -m "New Commit"`
2. `git pull` (*This will merge based on the ort strategy*)
3. `git push origin <current_branch>`

Comment: +1 for "... *not suggested to use --force during git push as it has potential to* ...".  Using `--force` is something to be used with caution.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote the wrong thing and the commit has not yet been pushed, you can do the following to change the commit message:

```
$ git commit --amend
```

This will open your default text editor, where you can edit the message. On the other hand, you can do this all in one command:

```
$ git commit --amend -m 'xxxxxxx'
```

If you have already pushed the message, you can amend the commit and force push, but this is not recommended.

To force push : `git push --force`