# Edit last pushed commit's message

Tags: git, github

After making use of the command to stage, commit and push all at once I asked for here [Git command to commit all changes including files removed or created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287206/git-command-to-commit-all-changes-including-files-removed-or-created), I've typed the wrong commit message and then pushed it to my Github account. I'm the only contributor to my repo so there's no *pulling* issues to fear.

I've followed the advice given here [Changing git commit message after push (given that no one pulled from remote)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981194/changing-git-commit-message-after-push-given-that-no-one-pulled-from-remote) and here [Edit an incorrect commit message in Git that has already been pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153760/edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git-that-has-already-been-pushed) which is basically to do:

```
git commit --amend
```

which opens up my text editor (Sublime) displaying the message of the last commit. Once in there I modify this message, save and close the file. After that I type:

```
git push origin master --force
```

which appears to work fine. But if I now do a :

```
git log
```

I keep seeing the wrong (ie: the old) message in my last commit and my Github account shows no changes whatsoever. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sure you are on the right branch?

Comment: I only have one branch: the master branch.

Comment: what if you do `git push origin HEAD:master --force`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience Sublime doesn't work well with git propmts.
Try passing the correct message directly with

```
git commit --amend -m <message>
```

and see if it works.

If it does you might have to switch to gVim or some other editor, that uses a single process.

I don't exactly know what the problem is with Sublime Text but I guess the first process just spawns another one and quits. Because of this git thinks the editing is finished and commits before you actually modified the file.

Comment: what platform are you running Sublime on? have you seen http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html

Comment: Yep, that was it. I applied this solution and it worked, I would have never guessed `Sublime` was the issue. I'll switch back to editing in `leafpad`. Thank you very much!
PS: @tcovo I use elementary OS which is based on Ubuntu 12.04.