# How to undo pushed revert in git?

Tags: git

I have reverted some code and pushed into a remote git repository. How can I "un revert" the changes even though it was pushed into a remote repository.

Please find below what I have done:

```
git revert commit_id    
git push origin branch_name
```

Now can I undo the revert?

Comment: Google, there are enough topics on that... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441902/undo-a-git-commit-after-push-using-reverse-patch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push

Comment: On undoing a git revert http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662543/is-there-any-way-to-undo-the-effects-of-git-revert-head and quite specific http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728093/how-to-i-un-revert-a-reverted-git-commit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your change has been `push`ed. Do not change others' history!

```
git checkout branch_name
git revert revert_id
git push origin branch_name
```